# gnu make - force exit without deleting the target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm incrementally verifying my build output and I want to be able to exit after a given recipe is executed.

If the original recipe is

```
$(HEADER_BUILD)/mpversion.h: FORCE | $(HEADER_BUILD)
    $(Q)$(PYTHON) $(PY_SRC)/makeversionhdr.py $@
```

I want to be able to add one line at the end like so

```
$(HEADER_BUILD)/mpversion.h: FORCE | $(HEADER_BUILD)
    $(Q)$(PYTHON) $(PY_SRC)/makeversionhdr.py $@
    some_command
```

and `some_command` should merely stop the execution of the makefile without interfering with the rest of the recipe.

If I set `some_command` as `exit 1`, I get

> ../py/py.mk:269: recipe for target 'build-gnu/genhdr/mpversion.h'
>   failed make: *** [build-gnu/genhdr/mpversion.h] Error 1 make: ***
>   Deleting file 'build-gnu/genhdr/mpversion.h'

If I set `some_command` as `$(error)`, the recipe isn't even executed even though it's BEFORE the `$(error)`

Is there such a command that stops executing the makefile but doesn't delete the target?

**UPDATE**
I've found this hack: make [`.PRECIOUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Interrupts.html#Interrupts) depend on the target and add `exit 1` as the last line in the recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you want to keep is an **intermediate** file (not mentioned as target or dependency of a rule - but possibly implied via a pattern rule), then you'll need to make it a dependency of `.PRECIOUS`.

Otherwise, it should be sufficient to temporarily remove or comment out the `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` target that we all put in every Makefile.